# How do I retrieve the role of my connected user and display it on my dashboard?

Tags: cakephp

I would like to display the role of my user connected with CakePHP4 but I can't find how to do it, I can already display his name and others but as for the name of the role it doesn't work I just have access to it 'Id of the role that is in my user table

On my sidebar view of my dashboard

```
<?php $administrateur = $this->request->getAttribute('identity'); ?>
     <h6 class="mb-0"><?= $administrateur->pseudo?></h6>
     <span>
     <?= $administrateur->role->nom ?>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use cakephp 4.3 with the cakephp/authentication 2.9 plugin. (https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/authentication-component.html)

I request the logged in users data inside the controller action.

```
public function view(){
$user = $this->Authentication->getIdentity();
$this->set(compact('user'));
}
```

I prefer using `$this->Authentication->getIdentity();` couse the results are easier for me to use, than `$this->request->getAttribute('identity');`

You can `debug($user);` within the view template and see which data it contains and have simple access to them.
I can access the role in the view template by

```
<?= $user->role =>
```

If you want to display the role *in just one view*, the example above works just fine.

If you want to display it *on multiple pages*, like in a menu i recommend reading about ViewCells:
https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/cells.html#creating-a-cell